# Allowed types using the contacts api in android

Tags: android, contacts

Using the contacts api how do i get all allowed types for phone, email, postal address, etc. to fill a dropdown similar to the one in the contacts application?? For example in the drop down for Phone I would like to see these - TYPE_HOME, TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_WORK, TYPE_FAX_WORK, TYPE_FAX_HOME, TYPE_PAGER, TYPE_OTHER, TYPE_CALLBACK, TYPE_CAR, TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN, TYPE_ISDN, TYPE_MAIN, TYPE_OTHER_FAX, TYPE_RADIO, TYPE_TELEX, TYPE_TTY_TDD, TYPE_WORK_MOBILE, TYPE_WORK_PAGER, TYPE_ASSISTANT, TYPE_MMS properly translated into the respective labels.  similarly for email, etc. Hope the question is clear now. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not get any responses, I have ended up doing this...  Sample code shown for getting phone types.  I was hoping that that there might be a more elegant way to do this where a future addition of a type is taken care of automatically rather than having to edit the source

```
public void createPhoneTypes() {

    phoneTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ASSISTANT);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CALLBACK);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CAR);
    phoneTypes
            .add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ISDN);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MMS);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER_FAX);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_PAGER);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_RADIO);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TELEX);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TTY_TDD);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_PAGER);
    phoneTypes.add(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);

}



public String[] getAllPhoneTypeLabels() {
    String[] stypes = new String[phoneTypes.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<phoneTypes.size(); i++) {
        stypes[i] = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), phoneTypes.get(i), "").toString();
    }
    return stypes;
}
```